# Lists, For Loops, Ranges, Indexes

Tags: python, loops, range

```
def garden(seedList):
  flower = [2, 5, 12]
  flowers = []
  for each in range(len(seedList)):
    totalFlowers = flowers.append(seedList[each] * flower[each])
    x = sum(totalFlowers)
  return totalFlowers
```

I am getting error: `The error was:iteration over non-sequence
Inappropriate argument type.
An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.`

The problem that I need to solve:

> Write a function that calculates the total amount of flowers given the number of seeds for each type of flower. The seedList parameter will contain the amount of seeds you
>   have. Each seed will produce a certain number of flowers. One petunia seed will produce 2 flowers.One daisy seed will produce 5 flowers. One rose seed will produce 12 flowers.seeds for each type of flower. The seedList parameter will contain the amount of seeds you
>   have. You should return an integer with the total number of flowers you will have in your garden.

Comment: Looping by index is a massively bad idea in Python - it's harder to read, slower and less flexible. When used to iterate over two lists at once like this, it also means the behaviour is much more unstable. Loop over the values! `for each in range(len(seedList)):` -> `for seed, flower_ in zip(seedList, flower):` and `flowers.append(seedList[each] * flower[each])` -> `flowers.append(seed * flower_)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is `list.append` modifies the list in place and returns `None`.

```
totalFlowers = flowers.append(seedList[each] * flower[each])
```

So your  code is actually doing :

```
x = sum(None)
```

A working version of your code:

```
def garden(seedList):
  flower = [2, 5, 12]
  flowers = []
  for each in range(len(seedList)):
      flowers.append(seedList[each] * flower[each])

  return sum(flowers)
```

A better solution solution using `zip`:

```
def garden(seedList):
  flower = [2, 5, 12]
  totalFlowers = sum ( x*y for x,y in zip(flower, seedList) )
  return totalFlowers
```